# How to group and average a dataset by order then plot a broken line plot?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that contains 5000 examinee's ability estimation with their test score, and they are both continuous variables. Since there are too many examinees, it would be messy to plot out all their scores, so I wish to draw a 'broken line plot' or 'conditional mean plot', that average the test scores of several examines that have similar ability levels at a time, and plot their average score against their average ability. Like the plot below.
[image]

I already managed to do this with the codes below.

```
df<-cbind(rnorm(100,set.seed(123)),sample(100,set.seed(123)),) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames(c("ability","score"))   #simulate the dataset
df<-df[order(df$ability),]  #sort the data from low to high according to the ability varaible

seq<-round(seq(from=1, to=nrow(df), length.out=10),0) #divide the data equally to nine groups (which is also gonna be the 9 points that appear in my plot)

b<-data.frame()
for (i in 1:9) {
  b[i,1]<-mean(df[seq[i]:seq[i+1],1])    #calculate the mean of the ability by group
  b[i,2]<-mean(df[seq[i]:seq[i+1],2])   # calculate the mean of test score by group
}.
```

I got the mean of the ability and test score using this for loop, and it looks like this
[image]

and finally, do the plot

```
plot(b$V1,b$V2, type='b',
     xlab="ability",
     ylab="score",
     main="Conditional score")
```

These codes meet my goal, but I can't help thinking if there's a simpler way to do this. Drawing a broken line plot by averaging the data that is sorted from low to high seems to be a normal task.
I wonder if there is any function or trick for this. All ideas are welcome! :)

Comment: Your code has several errors. You can easiliy verify by copying it to R and run it. Also the way your currently calculate the means, it will count the cut points twice, e.g. row 12 will be counted for the mean of the first AND second group. And so on for the next seq value that will be counted in the second AND thrid group.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to create the data to be plotted using dplyr:

```
set.seed(123)
df<-cbind(rnorm(100,1),sample(100,50)) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames(c("ability","score"))   #simulate the dataset

df<-df[order(df$ability),]  #sort the data from low to high according to the ability varaible
df$id <- seq(1, nrow(df))
df %>% mutate(bin = ntile(id, 10)) %>% 
  group_by(bin) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(meanAbility = mean(ability, na.rm=T),
                   meanScore = mean(score, na.rm=T)) %>% 
  as.data.frame()  

        bin meanAbility meanScore
1    1 -0.81312770      41.6
2    2 -0.09354171      52.3
3    3  0.29089892      54.4
4    4  0.68490709      45.8
5    5  0.93078744      59.8
6    6  1.17380069      34.0
7    7  1.42942368      41.3
8    8  1.64965315      40.1
9    9  1.95290596      35.6
10  10  2.50277510      52.9
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the whole thing a bit differently (note also that your code has several errors and won't run the way you were showing.

The exmaple below will lead to different numbers than yours (due to the random generation of numbers and your non-working code).

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(ability = rnorm(100),
                 score   = sample(100)) %>%
  arrange(ability) %>%
  mutate(seq = ntile(n = 9)) %>%
  group_by(seq) %>%
  summarize(mean_ability = mean(ability),
            mean_score   = mean(score))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
    seq mean_ability mean_score
  <int>        <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1  -1.390807     45.25   
2     2  -0.7241746    56.18182
3     3  -0.4315872    49      
4     4  -0.2223723    48.81818
5     5   0.06313174   56.36364
6     6   0.3391321    42      
7     7   0.6118022    53.27273
8     8   1.021438     50.54545
9     9   1.681746     53.54545
```